# Float:right not working? [Bootstrap 3 Panel]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap 3 project at the moment and i have added a button called "Add Shipment, i want this button to stay fixed to the right hand side of the panel but when I give it the style of float:right or class of pull-right, it doesn't work.

The design must be responsive so therefore I cannot just give it a class of float: left and then put margin-left: XXX

Please let me know if you know how to solve this, the code and screenshot are below.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:-20px;">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-table" style="border-radius:50px">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#EFEFEF; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; height:45px; width:auto">
            <div class="panel-title" style="padding:0; width:auto" >


            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width:200px; margin-top:7px; margin-left:10px; float:left">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter">
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group" style="float:left; margin-left:25px; margin-top:6px">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">All</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            </div>

             <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top:6px; float:right">Add Shipment</button>

            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:#F2F2F2; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; height:200px">  



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current screenshot of results from that code:

[image]

Comment: I have listed the EXACT code of where the error persists and a screenshot of its results, that isn't hard to work from.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your `float: left` just above it?

Comment: _“that isn't hard to work from”_ – yeah, right, and I’m gonna set up a working example myself now to help you with _your_ problem …

Comment: Don't understand it floats right when I view it.. http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/27/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried copying and pasting your code to see how things look, and it looks fine. I see that the Add Shipment button is pulled to the right. You must have something in your CSS stylesheet that is preventing the button from being floated to the right

Comment: @Aidan: And you still think a live example of your problem is too much to ask …?

Comment: If you can provide your CSS stylesheet I can probably checkout what's going on